# Use modifier key to right-click in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

Is there a way to hold a modifier-key (alt, ctrl etc.) + left-click to right-click?

Maybe there is some software that allows you to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). This script should do it:

^LButton::RButton

For <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Left mouse = Right mouse